# How to set a collection within a class? C#

Tags: c#

I have a class called TabTopBar that has a Collection Properties

```
class TabTopBar : Drawable
{

    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Tab> Tabs { get; }

    public TabTopBar()
    {        }
}
```

I would like to create a TabTopBar class by adding a collection of Tab like this: (class Tab is defined elsewhere)

```
new TabTopBar(){Tabs = {new Tab("testing",SculptTerrainTab()) } }
```

However, this is the error I got:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
UI.Controls.TabTopBar.Tabs.get returned null.

EDIT
[image]
the result persists.

Comment: why don't you have `set`?

Answer (score 0):

```
It should be  as follow
    
        new TabTopBar() { Tabs = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Tab> { new Tab("testing", SculptTerrainTab()) } }
    
    
    class TabTopBar : Drawable
    {
    
    //make sure you have setter
        public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Tab> Tabs { get; set; }
    
     

//initialize in constructor
    Initialize the Tabs in constructor
     public TabTopBar()
        {     
    Tabs= new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Tab>();
    
       }
    
    }
```

Comment: although the answer is correct please explain why - and offer other options (for instance initialization within ctor)

Comment: The problem persists..

Comment: Pls try with the updated code - //initialize in constructor
        Initialize the Tabs in constructor
         public TabTopBar()
            {     
        Tabs= new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Tab>();
        
           }

Answer (score 0):

## Example 1

With this class definition

```
class MyClass
{
    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<string> TheStrings { get; } = new();
}
```

Notes:

- Just a getter, the "TheStrings" immediately gets assigned a value that cannot be changed later
- Depending on your C# version, you may need `new Collection<string>()` instead of just `new()`

Then you can do

```
    var mc = new MyClass
    {
        TheStrings = { "a", "b" }
    };
```

Note

- The `{...}` syntax assignes values to the *existing* list or collection

## Example 2

This class definition with both a getter and a setter

```
class MyClass
{
    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<string> TheStrings { get; set; }
}
```

needs the TheStrings collection to be initialized before use:

```
    var mc = new MyClass
    {
        TheStrings = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<string> { "a", "b" }
    };
```

- The `()` after `Collection<string>` is optional in this case

See also the docs: [Object and Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers).